# How to implement an event driven model in PHP?

Tags: php

How could one build a system using PHP that tracks every event that occurs? Such as when someone comments on something, likes something or changes something.

The only thing that comes to mind right now is by the use of query strings when ever one invokes a command.

Comment: There's no problem described, which is offtopic for this site. Also, what you're looking for is too vague. Event-driven PHP? From what side is it event driven? Use of query strings? Your thoughts are all over the place, try to elaborate it more.

Comment: I understand the basic question - this is rather like the Event system in Symfony Components. However, I'd say you are going about it the wrong way - it's not ideal to choose a design pattern and work out how to fit it to the problem you have. It's best to look at the problem you have and decide what design pattern would be appropriate to solve the issue. What might need to be notified when someone comments on something? In general if you know beforehand what functionality is required here, just add it into the comment handler.

Comment: Think of it as the same thing when you look at all your facebook statuses or notifications of what is happening on the system. In essence these are all transitions of states. From one state to another. The system would handle these state changes and insert them into a database of activities.

Comment: OK, but the reason why you might implement an event pattern is if you cannot determine in advance what things need to happen at the triggering of the event. However, in most applications, there are a fixed number of things that will or may happen, and so an event-driven model is not required. Instead, when someone adds a comment, a script is called that runs those things that need to happen (e.g. add comment to database, add to activity log, update screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the [Observer pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php).